# Issue on running a JAVA 13 JAX-RS project in Tomcat 9

Tags: java, jax-rs, tomcat9

I'm working on this simple project and have this problem:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /RestTestThree/myService/Calculator/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.30
```

I use this setting: JDK 13, Eclipse 2019-12, Tomcat 9.

I tried different URLs and I hope this one is the correct one:

```
http://localhost:8080/RestTestThree/myService/Calculator/
```

I tried both model 3 and 4. Tried different dependencies and versions.

When trying to run this project, at some point the Tomcat even won't start, giving the error

> Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

My files are as follows.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.RestTestThree</groupId>
<artifactId>RestTestThree</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>13</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>RestTestThree</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.Calculator</param-value>  <!--comma separated packages -->
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Simple REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Calculator.java**

```
package com;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Calculator")
public class Calculator
{
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello()
    {
        return "Working...";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/Add")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String add()
    {
        return "<div>Sum = 10</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After downgrade java 13 to 11 all work perfect. Need convert project to 11 some.